# How do I symlink all files from one directory to another in bash?

Tags: bash, symlink, ln

I want to link ( `ln -s` ) all files that are in `/mnt/usr/lib/` into `/usr/lib/`

There are lots of files, how can it be done quickly? :)

Comment: How many files is "lots", and how fast you deem "fast"?

Comment: This is 50:50 whether it would fit "serverfault" or "superuser", but it isn't programming, so not for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 236):

```
ln -s /mnt/usr/lib/* /usr/lib/
```

I guess, this belongs to superuser, though.

Comment: This does not include hidden files, and it links whole directories. If either of these is not what you want, see my answer. Otherwise, it's the shortest way.

Comment: You're right. But libraries aren't hidden usually. In any case dotfiles are involved your solution comes in more handy.

Comment: will it point to the other folder permanently?

Comment: @YuPPie I guess, it just creates hardlink to every file in the directory. (this is what I wanted today, so +1 :D)

Comment: @SargeBorsch It creates symbolic links (hard links are different).

Comment: Yeah, for sure. I was too stupid at these days, now I understand this stuff better.

Comment: This is not working for me. I just get * as soft link instead of all files and folders inside lib

Answer (score 102):

GNU `cp` has an option to create symlinks instead of copying.

```
cp -rs /mnt/usr/lib /usr/
```

Note this is a GNU extension not found [in POSIX `cp`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/cp/).

Comment: Your current directory should be /usr/ to make symbolic link this way

Comment: @caf If the destination is existing folder, then the lib folder is created inside in /usr/ folder

Comment: Good answer. Can also be used to create hardlinks with -l instead of -s.

Comment: Is there an option to copy hidden files as well?

Comment: @sinekonata sure you can use 
`cp -rs /myconfigfolder/. /mynewconfigfolder/`
So should everything included hiddenfiles symlinked

Answer (score 21):

```sh
ln -s /mnt/usr/lib/* /usr/lib/
```

Answer (score 21):

The posted solutions will not link any hidden files. To include them, try this:

```
cd /usr/lib
find /mnt/usr/lib -maxdepth 1 -print "%P\n" | while read file; do ln -s "/mnt/usr/lib/$file" "$file"; done
```

If you should happen to want to recursively create the directories and only link files (so that if you create a file within a directory, it really is in `/usr/lib` not `/mnt/usr/lib`), you could do this:

```
cd /usr/lib
find /mnt/usr/lib -mindepth 1 -depth -type d -printf "%P\n" | while read dir; do mkdir -p "$dir"; done
find /mnt/usr/lib -type f -printf "%P\n" | while read file; do ln -s "/mnt/usr/lib/$file" "$file"; done
```

Comment: I believe this should also work as a way to wildcard in hidden files, if you have extended globbing turned on in bash. It matches everything starting with a dot, followed by something other than nothing or another dot (i.e. it excludes `./` and `../`): `ln -s /mnt/usr/lib/.!(|.)* /usr/lib`