# Symlink dotfiles

Tags: unix, vim, command-line, dotfiles

I am having trouble symlinking dotfiles. I have a folder in my home directory  ~/dotfiles which I have synced to a github repo. I am trying to take my .vimrc file in ~/dotfiles/.vimrc and create a symbolic link to put it at ~/.vimrc. To do this I type in

```
ln -s ~/dotfiles/.vimrc ~/.vimrc
```

But when I run that it says

```
ln: /Users/me/.vimrc: File exists
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: protip: In newer versions of Vim, you can also store your `vimrc` inside of your `~/vim` directory for easier storage. This makes the path: `~/.vim/vimrc`. See `:h vimrc`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That error message means that you already have a file at `~/.vimrc`, which `ln` is refusing to overwrite.  Either delete the `~/.vimrc` and run `ln` again or let `ln` delete it for you by passing the `-f` option:

```
ln -s -f ~/dotfiles/.vimrc ~/.vimrc
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a better solution for managing dotfiles without using symlinks or any other tool, just a git repo initialized with `--bare`.

A bare repository is special in a way that they omit working directory, so you can create your repo anywhere and set the `--work-tree=$HOME` then you don't need to do any work to maintain it.

**Approach**

first thing to do is, create a bare repo

```bash
git init --bare $HOME/.dotfiles
```

To use this bare repo, you need to specify `--git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/` and  `--work-tree=$HOME`, better is to create an alias

```bash
alias dotfiles='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME
```

At this point, all your configuration files are being tracked, and you can easily use the newly registered dotfiles command to manage the repository, ex :-

```bash
# to check the status of the tracked and untracked files 
dotfiles status

# to add a file 
dotfiles commit .tmux.conf -m ".tmux.conf added"

# push new files or changes to the github
dotfiles push origin main
```

I also use this way to sync and store my dotfiles, [see my dotfiles repository](https://github.com/kalkayan/dotfiles) and can read at [Storing dotfiles with Git](https://engineeringwith.kalkayan.com/series/developer-experience/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com) where I wrote about managing for multiple devices.

Answer (score 3):

### How to symlink all dotfiles in a directory recursively

1. Have a dotfiles directory that is structured as to how they should be structured at `$HOME`

   ```sh
   dotfiles_home=~/dotfiles/home  # for example
   ```
2. `cp -rsf "$dotfiles_home"/. ~`

   - `-r`: Recursive, create the necessary directory for each file
   - `-s`: Create symlinks instead of copying
   - `-f`: **Overwrite existing files** (previously created symlinks, default `.bashrc`, etc)
   - `/.`: Make sure `cp` "copy" the contents of `home` instead of the `home` directory itself.

###### Tips

Just like `ln`, if you want no [headache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10370/307359) or [drama](https://askubuntu.com/q/994103/356625), **use an absolute path for the first argument** like the example above.

###### Note

This only works with GNU `cp` (preinstalled in Ubuntu), not [POSIX `cp`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/cp/). Check your `man cp`, you can install GNU coreutils if needed.

###### Thanks

To [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347216/9157799) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347105/how-do-i-symlink-all-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-bash#comment125442458_1347216).

Answer (score 0):

Use GNU Stow for symlink your dotfiles.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).